# Web3ReactProvider || Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') || Error while using web3-react/core

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, react, web3-providers

[image: Eroor in web3ReactProvider]
getting this error while consuming the web3provider,
Did the same configuration as per the tutorial.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you share the code that causes the issue? What version of web3 were you using? Any other detail could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Please downgrade your version @web3-react/core. I just changed my web3-react/core to 6.1.9 and it's worked

Comment: this answer would be better if you specify why this is a fix.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably on v8 but using the old v6 wrapper like
`<Web3ReactProvider getLibrary={getLibrary}>` but in v8 you need to define your wrapper like `<Web3ReactProvider connectors={connectors}>` where 'connectors' is an array of your initialized connectors like :

```
const connectors = [
  [metaMask, metaMaskHooks],
  [walletConnectV2, walletConnectV2Hooks],
  [coinbaseWallet, coinbaseWalletHooks],
];
```